# Apprently simple proportion question.

Tags: ratio

There are 5000 buyers of apples, who each on average buy 12 apples a month.

There are two types of apple buyers, those that buy red apples, and those that buy green apples.

The red apple buyers buy an average of 5 a month. The green apple buyers buy an average of 14 a month.

What proportion of the 5000 apple buyers are red apple buyers?

Completely stuck.

I'd really appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the number of red apple buyers be x, then those buying green apples are (5000-x). the total number of apples they buy is 5000 *12 = 60,000. This is also equal to the sum of the number of apples that red and green apple buyers buy. Therefore,

x*5 + (5000-x)*14 = 60,000

which gives x = 10,000/9 = 1111.11

You can ignore the .11 as number of people can't be fractional

Comment: Gah, feel so dumb for not thinking of the 5000-x bit. Thanks a lot!